# Google Apps Script - copy row & paste as values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy one range to another using GAS - but I need the range to 'paste as values'

This code works (but pastes as formulas):

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("16S3INZFMQDY3yguNZ2QHvzMQXI1Kf97DkSvcYyZeiHM").getSheets()[1]

var source_range = sheet.getRange("D12:M12");
var target_range = sheet.getRange("D10:M10");
source_range.copy(target_range);
```

This code does not work (error = Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Range) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.copyValuesToRange.)

```
function copyRange() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("16S3INZFMQDY3yguNZ2QHvzMQXI1Kf97DkSvcYyZeiHM").getSheets()[1]

var source_range = sheet.getRange("D12:M12");
var target_range = sheet.getRange("D10:M10");
source_range.copyValuesToRange(target_range);
}
```

Can anyone please help as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
source_range.copy(target_range);
```

#### To:

```
source_range.copyTo(target_range, { contentsOnly: true });
```

or, when you want to use `copyValuesToRange`, how about the following modification?

```
source_range.copyValuesToRange(sheet, 4, 10, 10, 10);
```

or

```
source_range.copyValuesToRange(target_range.getGridId(), 4, 10, 10, 10);
```

or, when `getValues` and `setValues` are used, how about the following modification?

```
target_range.setValues(source_range.getValues());
```

#### References:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)
- [copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)